# TabBar does not change color in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I want to change the color of the tabBar in SwiftUI.

This is how i try it:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            Group {
                HomeView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Übersicht", systemImage: "house")
                    }
                SettingsView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Einstellungen", systemImage: "gear")
                    }
            }
            .toolbarBackground( Color.white, for: .tabBar)
            .toolbar(.visible, for: .tabBar)
        }
    }
}
```

The color of the tabBar stays at the default gray.
I followed this article: https://sarunw.com/posts/swiftui-tabview-color/

I am running this code with XCode Version `15.0 beta 3 (15A5195k)` on iOS 17.0

Comment: Have you tried adding the .toolbarBackground modifier to the child-views of TabView? Like adding .toolbarBackground to both  HomeView() & SettingsView()  calls

Comment: yes i also tried that first

Comment: have you tried this: `init() { UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .green }`

Comment: Yes that works, but i read somewhere that it is not a good idea to use it because it depends on UITabBar, and it would be nice to know why the version i tried did not work